# How to print a created handle information in UVM?

Tags: system-verilog, uvm

I create an object handle in UVM usually with `new` or `create` to allocate memory.  Is there any possible way to print about created handle information?
For example, I made the below example.

```
task body;
    i2c_packet pkt;
    pkt = i2c_packet::type_id::create("pkt");   
    ...
```

`i2c_packet` has bunch of variables.
After `pkt` is created, can I print `pkt` (`uvm_sequence_item`'s variables) information, and how do I know `pkt` is created as well or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the `uvm_sequence_item` class is extended from the `uvm_object` class, it inherits the `print` method which is used to display the class variables.

```
task body;
    i2c_packet pkt;
    pkt = i2c_packet::type_id::create("pkt");
    pkt.print();
```

Use the `uvm_object_utils` and `uvm_field_*` macros in your `uvm_sequence_item` class to control what gets printed.

```
class i2c_packet extends uvm_sequence_item;
    ...
    `uvm_object_utils_begin(i2c_packet)
        `uvm_field_int(data, UVM_DEFAULT)
    `uvm_object_utils_end
```

For a code example, refer to [UVM Object Print](https://www.chipverify.com/uvm/uvm-object-print).

Refer also to the [UVM class reference](https://www.accellera.org/images/downloads/standards/uvm/UVM_1.1_Class_Reference_Final_06062011.pdf).